# Html cant align form and button

Tags: html, css

I tried making a chat service, and it worked but now im with a problem.
I want to align these two form elements, so they are on one line. So the the 'send' button gets moved a little higher so it is in place.

I tried this:

```
position: relative;
```

I added that to the css. But no result.
I don't know how to solve this problem. Since im not an css genuis.

code:
html:

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div id="chattextarea" id="postform">
<form action="" method="POST">
<textarea name="styled-textarea" id="styled" onfocus="this.value=''; setbg('#e5fff3');" onblur="setbg('white')" placeholder="Enter an chat message here...">Enter an chat message here...</textarea>&nbsp;
<input type="hidden" name="chatid" value="<?php echo $chatid ?>">
<input type="submit" value="Send" id="chatmessagesend">
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#postform {
    position: relative;
}
```

Picture:

[image]
Thansk in advance

Comment: Your code and markup please.

Comment: Postedthe code (html + css)

Comment: @user3813511 Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing an opening `div`. Also, [this](http://jsfiddle.net/EWd6a/) will work:

```
<p>&nbsp;</p><div>
<div id="chattextarea" id="postform">
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <textarea name="styled-textarea" id="styled" onfocus="this.value=''; setbg('#e5fff3');"              onblur="setbg('white')" placeholder="Enter an chat message here...">Enter an chat message         here...
            </textarea>&nbsp;
            <input type="hidden" name="chatid" value="<?php echo $chatid ?>">
            <input type="submit" value="Send" id="chatmessagesend">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
* { margin:0;padding:0; }
#postform {
    position: relative;

}

form > #chatmessagesend { vertical-align: top; }
```

Answer (score 1):

try using:

```
 #chattextarea{
   vertical-align: top;
 }
```

Comment: No result. Just stayed the same. css now: #postform {
 vertical-align: top
}